# call notifyDataSetChanged() frequently

Tags: android, notifydatasetchanged

i have an adapter for my listview ，then i need to refresh it with the notifydatasetchanged method in the SensorChange method.you konw SensorChange meodthod was called frequently and quickly...

after a while ,the listview in the screen was dispeared,and the getview method stop,did not call any more. when i remove the notifydatasetchanged  method ,it was fine, but the item of listview can not refresh. why?

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent evt) {if(mPoiListAdapter != null){
        mPoiListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent evt) {

                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mPoiListAdapter != null) {
                            mPoiListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                    }
                }, 1500);
            }
```

Comment: Can't you reuse the `Handler`?

Comment: but now ,the onItemClickListener of the listview can not work ,just work sometimes. but if i remove the  notifyDataSetChanged in the SensorChange method. it work fine. how to solve this problem ?